# How to load helper from app/views/helpers CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

In our project we have placed the helper inside app/view/helper folder. It works fine in the application. The issue I am facing is that I using facebook plugin by webtechnick, and when I use helper in the plugin view, it tries to load the helper from `CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php` and gives warning

```
Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::scriptBlock does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 142]
```

Can any one suggest what is the solution? how can I force the use of the html helper from app/views/helpers in my plugin?

Comment: what cake version? i am confused by your casing...

Comment: check the helpers named correctly; and surely the plugin's helper should be in the plugins helper directory - not your apps.

Comment: mark the verison is 1.3.2.
Let me explain it, the html helper file is in app/views/helpers directory (I think someone has overridden the default). In the entire application when I use var $helpers = array('Html'); the function implementation in html helper from app/views/helpers directory comes and works fine.
I have a job to write a plugin and when I use var $helpers = array('Html'); in plugin view, the implementation of helper comes from CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php and gives warning. The implementation of helper should come from app/views/helpers instead.

Comment: If my statements are confusing then the most simple question I am asking is why Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::scriptBlock does not exist [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 142] is coming in a plugin view? the same works fine for application views. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone might have edited the core cake installation.  You might want to download a fresh copy of cake and manually browse to the right location to verify that the core helper exists.

When overriding the default helper by creating an alternate, the original does not need to be removed.  The app will check for copies in the app directory before checking the cake directory.  Both html helper files should exist.

You are looking for the file with the following path: `CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/html.php`

You should be able to include 'Html' helper from within a plugin without referring to the app directory at all.

If the core cake html helper is missing, you can likely fix your error by simply replacing it from the fresh copy you downloaded.

Oh yeah, the best practice is never to alter the core files in any way, so make sure you create a backup before messing with anything.  In this case, you are attempting to put BACK something that someone may have removed.